# "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column" error when inserting number

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

Doing a college assignment and can't figure out the error

```
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


1. INSERT INTO HR_EMPLOYEES 
2.     (EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
3. VALUES (203010, 'SUSAN', 'LYNCH', 'SLYNCH@GMAIL.COM', 0878457391, TO_DATE('2017/07/08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 93, 36000, 10, 1900, 60);
```

Here is the table I'm trying to insert into

```
CREATE TABLE HR_EMPLOYEES 
    (
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20),
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    SALARY NUMERIC (8,2),
    COMMISSION_PCT NUMERIC (2,2),
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6),
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
    );
```

Here is the insert

```
INSERT INTO HR_EMPLOYEES 
    (EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (203010, 'SUSAN', 'LYNCH', 'SLYNCH@GMAIL.COM', 0878457391, TO_DATE('2017/07/08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 93, 36000, 10, 1900, 60);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You can start with quoting `0878457391` as `'0878457391'`

Comment: done but still error

Comment: Since the precision for `COMMISSION_PCT` should at least be **4** eg. `COMMISSION_PCT NUMERIC (4,2)`, as you're trying to insert a value( **10** ) with length **2** + scale( **2** ) = **4**